# Swap IIS Bindings Between Two Sites

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to swap bindings between 2 sites is IIS in Powershell.  The script below is working but it seems a little too complicated:

```powershell
    $site1Name = ''
    $site2Name = ''
    
    $site1 = Get-Website | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $site1Name}
    $site2 = Get-Website | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $site2Name}

    $site1Bindings = $site1 | Get-WebBinding
    $site2Bindings = $site2 | Get-WebBinding
    
    $site1 | Get-WebBinding | Remove-WebBinding
    $site2 | Get-WebBinding | Remove-WebBinding
    
    function Copy-Bindings
    {
        param($siteA_Bindings, [string]$siteB_Name)
         
        foreach ($binding in $siteA_Bindings)
        {
            $bindingInformation = $binding['bindingInformation'].Split(':')
            $ip = $bindingInformation[0]
            $port = $bindingInformation[1]
            
            if ($bindingInformation.Length -gt 2)
            {   
                $hostRecord = $bindingInformation[2]
            }
            else
            {   
                $hostRecord = ''
            }
            
            $protocol = $binding['protocol']
            New-WebBinding -Name $siteB_Name -Port $port -Protocol $protocol -IPAddress $ip -HostHeader $hostRecord
        }
    }
    
    Copy-Bindings $site1Bindings $site2Name
    Copy-Bindings $site2Bindings $site1Name
```

What I'd want is something more like this (in pseudo-code):

```powershell
    $site1Name = ''
    $site2Name = ''
    
    $site1 = Get-Website | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $site1Name}
    $site2 = Get-Website | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $site2Name}

    $site1Bindings = $site1 | Get-WebBinding
    $site2Bindings = $site2 | Get-WebBinding
    
    $site1 | Get-WebBinding | Remove-WebBinding
    $site2 | Get-WebBinding | Remove-WebBinding
    
    $site1Bindings | New-WebBinding -Name $site2Name
    $site2Bindings | New-WebBinding -Name $site1Name
```

Is there any way of simplifying it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no, it cannot be simplified down to the degree the psudocode desired is representing.The current function works well enough for an IPv4 site binding, but would need more tweaking for an IPv6 binding(split on [ and ] in addition to :).

The [help file for New-WebBinding](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790567.aspx) shows that while the parameters needed do take pipeline input, it is ByPropertyName(works if property name matches) not ByValue(works if object type matches).

Taking a closer look at what we get back from an example result of the `$site1Bindings` variable shows why. First, let's take a look at the object type:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $site2Bindings | GM

   TypeName:
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#bindings#binding
```

Unfortunately, the `New-WebBinding` doesn't accept that object type for input on any of the parameters. That rules out the direct use of it for pipelining into `New-WebBinding`. But, what about the property names inside the `$site2Bindings`? Here's an example of what that looks like:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $site2Bindings | FL

protocol           : http
bindingInformation : [2002:4000:200:9:900:e45e:e501:aa37]:80:
sslFlags           : 0
```

Well, `protocol` matches the name of a parameter, so that could be used via pipeline input, but that's the only one. Thus, you must chop the resulting information up and assign it to variables, just as you have done in your function. There may be a cleaner way to chop up the results, but no way to avoid it when using `New-WebBinding`.

Comment: Can you suggest a cleaner way to chop up the results (or an alternate to New-WebBinding which doesn't need that)?

Comment: I looked into some of the other `*IIS*` config cmdlets and found the same ugly bindinginformation formatting there as well. I'll look around to see if there are other alternatives.